# Find a recursive formula for a closed formula recursively at infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations, exponential-function, closed-form

I have a recursive sequence defined as such:

$$
\left(u_k \right) = \begin{cases}
    u_0 = 1                             \\
    u_k = u_{k-1} + u_{k-1} \cdot \frac{1}{n}
\end{cases}\quad \text{with}\ k,n \in \mathbb{N}
$$

I want $n$ to be as big as possible (close to infinity), and then $k$ would range from $[0;n]$ to compute the $n$-th term. I wrote:

$$\lim \limits_{\substack{n \to \infty\\k \to n}} u_k = \lim \limits_{\substack{n \to \infty\\k \to n}} \left( u_{k-1} + u_{k-1} \cdot \frac{1}{n} \right)$$

Can I write it this way?

This question is motivated by this limit which correspond to the closed formula of what I am trying to achieve recursively:

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n$$

This is similar to this little python script which uses recursion to compute $e$ if you choose $n$ to be large enough:

```
def euler(n):
    un = 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        un = un + un * 1/n
    return un

print(euler(100000))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a geometric progression. 
$$u_k=u_0\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^k=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^k.$$
Now, we see that the limit does not exist.

If you want a recursive formula for $a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n,$ so we can write something as this:
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}a_n,$$ where $a_1=2.$

Comment: I already know that, I was trying to define it **recursively** by formalizing my limit expression.

Comment: @eigenpussy It's something another. See please better my post.

Comment: In my limit definition, I let $k \to n$ and $n \to \infty$ so assuming $k = n$ the limit does exist and converges to $e \approx 2.71828$

Comment: @eigenpuss By your definition, $u$ is closed to $+\infty$ for any natural $n$.

Comment: Yes, I think you can't take a limit for a recursive formula that involves another limit. That is just not formally correct. I refer about the statement I wrote in my post.

Comment: @eigenpussy If you want to fix your problem, so open please,  another topic

Comment: I am not sure it deserves a new topic. I just wanted to know if something like $\lim \limits_{\substack{n \to \infty\\k \to n}} u_k = \lim \limits_{\substack{n \to \infty\\k \to n}} \left( u_{k-1} + u_{k-1} \cdot \frac{1}{n} \right)$ is correct in terms of notation. I guess not.

Comment: That was originally my question anyway.

Comment: @eigenpussy You can not make so because by your definition $u$ is a function of $k$ only. By your definition $n$ is a parameter.

Comment: How can I formally write: “choose an integer n as close to infinity as possible and evaluate the term $u_n$”?